# JS Get Wikipedia-JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, html, json

this is the link, Wikipedia provides nearby results.

```
 let latitude = 50
 let longitude = 8     
 "https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=coordinates%7Cpageimages%7Cpageterms&colimit=50&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=144&pilimit=50&wbptterms=description&generator=geosearch&ggscoord=" + latitude + "%7C" + longitude + "&ggsradius=10000&ggslimit=10&titles=Brauhaus";
```

How can I get this into an JS-object?

```
class NearbyLocation{
    constructor(){
        this.title
        this.imageUrl
        this.descriptionUrl
        this.description
        this.latitude
        this.longitude
    }
}
```

Thx!
pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an XHR (XMLHttpRequest) to make the call to the Wikipedia API. It returns a JSON string, so then you can use JSON.Parse to convert it into its Javascript object form. (It won't be a class, just a plain JS object, but that's all you need.)